# emacs loops in c at command screen

Tags: shell, loops

I have an assignment at emacs in C, to try some numbers as arguments, but I can't write a line each time to try that argument number.

I need one value that makes the code correct, and I can't see the `function1(int x)` code.

instead of writing this:

```
$ ./function1 0
0 is wrong
$ ./function1 1
1 is wrong
$ ./function1 2
2 is wrong
$ ./function1 3
3 is wrong
.
.
.

$ ./function1 1000
1000 is wrong
```

can I loop it?

Comment: What does this have to do with emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not specific to emacs, the shell buffer acts like a terminal window, so you are looking for a way to run your program with a sequence of arguments. You could write an emacs macro and repeat that 1000 times but it is cumbersome to insert variable values from inside a macro, it seems much easier to use the shell for this loop.

You can use the `xargs` command:

```
$ echo {1..1000} | xargs -n 1 ./function1
```

Or you can write a shell loop:

```
$ for i in {1..1000} ; do ./function1 $i ; done
```

To filter the correct answer, pipe the output to `grep`:

```
$ echo {1..1000} | xargs -n 1 ./function1 | grep -v wrong
```